# Dnsmasq Not Obeying dhcp-host Directive

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, dd-wrt

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.  I have several computers on an office lan and have always used dnsmasq embedded in a DD-WRT router to act as my DHCP server and DNS server.
I need some hosts to have the same IP address, and have configured DHCP as follows:

```
local=/lan/
expand-hosts
dhcp-authoritative

dhcp-host=20:cf:30:6c:07:0e,micah,192.168.1.10,infinite
dhcp-host=FC:AA:14:E3:2F:48,jonah,192.168.1.11,infinite
dhcp-host=EC:B1:D7:F8:79:97,hp1,192.168.1.20,infinite
dhcp-host=34:64:A9:64:E9:73,hp2,192.168.1.21,infinite
dhcp-host=00:A0:D1:EB:4D:05,s16,192.168.1.30,infinite
dhcp-host=00:A0:D1:EB:4F:15,db1,192.168.1.31,infinite

#Example zeroconf
txt-record=_http._tcp.lan,paper=letter

# TFTP Server (must be set up on named server)
# Network booting from micah
# dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
# dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,micah.lan,192.168.1.10
```

Since upgrading, the host "micah" which is supposed to get the IP address 192.168.1.10 is getting 192.168.1.188.  I have done a dhcpdump while re-connecting the network and get this:

```
  TIME: 2020-10-01 16:06:32.582
    IP: 0.0.0.0 (20:cf:30:6c:7:e) > 255.255.255.255 (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
    OP: 1 (BOOTPREQUEST)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 36f77027
  SECS: 1
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 0.0.0.0
SIADDR: 0.0.0.0
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 20:cf:30:6c:07:0e:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         3 (DHCPREQUEST)
OPTION:  61 (  6) Client-identifier         00:6d:69:63:61:68
OPTION:  55 ( 17) Parameter Request List      1 (Subnet mask)
                                              2 (Time offset)
                                              6 (DNS server)
                                             12 (Host name)
                                             15 (Domainname)
                                             26 (Interface MTU)
                                             28 (Broadcast address)
                                            121 (Classless Static Route)
                                              3 (Routers)
                                             33 (Static route)
                                             40 (NIS domain)
                                             41 (NIS servers)
                                             42 (NTP servers)
                                            119 (Domain Search)
                                            249 (MSFT - Classless route)
                                            252 (MSFT - WinSock Proxy Auto Detect)
                                             17 (Root path)
                                            
OPTION:  57 (  2) Maximum DHCP message size 576
OPTION:  50 (  4) Request IP address        192.168.1.188
OPTION:  12 (  5) Host name                 micah
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  TIME: 2020-10-01 16:06:32.582
    IP: 192.168.1.1 (10:c3:7b:54:10:78) > 192.168.1.188 (20:cf:30:6c:7:e)
    OP: 2 (BOOTPREPLY)
 HTYPE: 1 (Ethernet)
  HLEN: 6
  HOPS: 0
   XID: 36f77027
  SECS: 1
 FLAGS: 0
CIADDR: 0.0.0.0
YIADDR: 192.168.1.188
SIADDR: 192.168.1.1
GIADDR: 0.0.0.0
CHADDR: 20:cf:30:6c:07:0e:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
 SNAME: .
 FNAME: .
OPTION:  53 (  1) DHCP message type         5 (DHCPACK)
OPTION:  54 (  4) Server identifier         192.168.1.1
OPTION:  51 (  4) IP address leasetime      -1 ()
OPTION:   1 (  4) Subnet mask               255.255.255.0
OPTION:  28 (  4) Broadcast address         192.168.1.255
OPTION:   6 (  4) DNS server                192.168.1.1
OPTION:  15 (  3) Domainname                lan
OPTION:  12 (  5) Host name                 micah
OPTION:   3 (  4) Routers                   192.168.1.1
```

I'm no networking expert and would like some help figuring out why the dhcp-host directive for micah is not being honored.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  After re-booting the problem went away.  I noticed that the 192.168.1.10 number was shown assigned in the Status/LAN section of the DD-WRT web interface, albeit with no hostname assigned.  Hitting "Delete" on that IP lease record had no effect.  So, I punted and rebooted the router.

Here's what I think happened:

1. When upgrading, I booted my micah host into an ubuntu live USB thumb drive as part of the installation.
2. Dnsmasq noticed the MAC address of my ethernet device and assigned 192.168.1.10 to the host, as directed by my dhcp-host setting.
3. The hostname "micah" was not set on the ubuntu live incarnation, naturally, so it was not set.
4. But the lease time was infinite.
5. When my actual host asked for an IP from Dsnmasq's DHCP server, it thought it was already reserved, so it handed out an IP from the dynamic range.
6. Thus, a number of services, such as ssh, were all pointing to a dead host and hanging.